# Finding probability using Var

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance

I'm stuck on the following question:

Suppose you toss three coins: two fair coins and a positively biased coin (more likely to show Heads than Tails). The variance of the total number of Heads in the three tosses is 0.55. What is the probability that the biased coin shows head?

To start off, I made the following expression: Var(2F+B) = 0.55

I then seperated and simplified to 2Var(F) + Var(B) = 0.55

I used the equation of Var for the binomial distribution (which is np(1-p)) to get

2(2*0.5)(1-0.5) + Var(B) = 0.55

so Var(B) = -0.45. I then used the same equation of Var again to get

p(1-p) = -0.45 but after expanding and solving the quadratic equation, I get 2 values for the probabilities that are less than 0 and greater than 1.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: Variance can't be negative (it is a sum of non-negative quantities).

Comment: You said $Var(F) = p(1-p)$ with $p = \frac{1}{2}$, but then you used $Var(F) = 2p(1-p)$ with $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: $F$ is the distribution of a single fair coin, not two.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are mistreating the distribution $F$.  If $F$ is the distribution for the number of Heads resulting from tossing two fair coins then you want to write $$\text{Var}(F+B)=\text{Var}(F)+\text{Var}(B)$$  We get $\text{Var}(F)=.5$ and all is good. We get $$.5+\text{Var}(B)=.55$$ which makes perfect sense.

But in your first expression, you appear to want $F$ to be the distribution for a single coin.  In that case you should have written $$\text{Var}(F_1+F_2+B)=2\text{Var}(F)+\text{Var}(B)$$

Where the $F_i$ are i.i.d. and both equal $F$.  But in this case $\text{Var}(F)=.25$ and again we get $.5+\text{Var}(B)=.55$

In either case, you should not have written $2F$ as no variable is being multiplied by $2$.

Comment: So my mistake is that when I wrote 2Var(F), I shouldn't have multiplied it by 2, but rather just keep that as an expression for me to know that it's 2 fair coins?

Comment: Not sure I follow you.  There is no $2F$.  If $F$ is the distribution of a single fair coin, then having two independent fair coins is not $2F$.  After all, $2F$ can only take the values $0$ and $2$, while the two fair coins could show exactly $1$.

Comment: So when i get .5+Var(B)=.55, and use the equation for Var again which is np(1-p), i get p(1-p) = 0.05, and when solving for p, i again get 2 values (p=0.95 and p=0.05). Is this correct, and so, which one is the right avlue for p? Or am I wong in using np(1-p)

Comment: Either value works.  Given the low variance, you know that the biased coin must, essentially, come up only $H$ or only $T$ and there's no way to know which (from the given data).

Comment: If you are confused by the formalism, write it all out explicitly.  There are only $8$ possible outcomes and, given $p$, you can easily work out the probability of each.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you assume Var to be liniear, [which it is not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties).

$Var(2F+B) = 2^2Var(F) + Var(B)$

Also note that the Variance can never be negative. Otherwise you are on a good path.

Comment: Variance is linear here, as the three coins are independent.  The OP should not have written $2F$.  Rather, it should be $F_1+F_2$ where $F_i$ is the usual single coin distribution and $F_1,F_2$ are independent.

Comment: I see - sorry, I missinterpreted that.